# Error occurred in deployment step Install App for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012

I got this error while trying to deploy an App in SharePoint 2013. The full error message is

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install App for SharePoint': Failed to install App for SharePoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow the the Steps Given below**

Create an isolated app domain on your development computer

Microsoft has provided also some PowerShell commmand to configure your SharePoint (link).

Start the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

```
 1. net start spadminv4
 2. net start sptimerv4
```

Create your isolated app domain your apps, for example "apps.developement.local".

```
1. Set-SPAppDomain "apps.developement.local"
```

Ensure that the SPSubscriptionSettingsService and AppManagementServiceInstance services are running.

```
1. Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"} | Start-SPServiceInstance
```

Verify that the SPSubscriptionSettingsService and AppManagementServiceInstance services are running.

```
1. Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"}
```

You must specify a farm admin account under which the SPSubscriptionService and AppManagementServiceInstance services will run. This farm admin account must be an SPManagedAccount. If your farm admin is not an SPManagedAccount, you can create a SPManagedAccount with your farm admin credentials by typing the following command in the SharePoint Management Shell (You will be prompted for the farm admin domain\user and password).

```
 1. $account = New-SPManagedAccount
```

Specify a farm admin account, application pool, and database settings for the SPSubscriptionService and AppManagementServiceInstance services.

```
1. $account = Get-SPManagedAccount "domain\user"
2. $appPoolSubSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SettingsServiceAppPool -Account $account
3. $appPoolAppSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name AppServiceAppPool -Account $account
4. $appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication –ApplicationPool $appPoolSubSvc –Name SettingsServiceApp –DatabaseName SettingsServiceDB
5. $proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy –ServiceApplication $appSubSvc
6. $appAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPoolAppSvc -Name AppServiceApp -DatabaseName AppServiceDB
7. $proxyAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $appAppSvc
```

Specify your tenant name by typing the following code in the SharePoint Management Shell.

```
1. Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "app" -Confirm:$false
```

Reference : http://www.mavention.nl/blog/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed

Answer (score 3):

> Go to Central Administration -> Services on Server

Check if the App Management Service and Subscription Service are started. You can use the following PowerShell to start them:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "A
ppManagementServiceInstance" -or $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsSe
rviceInstance"} | Start-SPServiceInstance
```

If they already are started, you will get the following warnings:

> WARNING: 'App Management Service' is already started on server
> 'SP2013-1-FLK'
>
> WARNING: 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings
> Service' is already started on server 'SP2013-1-FLK'

[image]