# Deployment Error in SharePoint APP

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-hosted-app

I get Error when Deploy that SharePoint App

> Error 1 Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for
>   SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action.

[image]

Comment: yes but this solution is not worked for here..

Comment: try this once https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/68419/30145

Comment: I also see this article but it is also not worked

Comment: What account are you using to to deploy the app? Are you RDP'ing into the server with that same account?

Comment: same account using administartor

Answer (score 2):

Try it with another account other than the Admin account but with farm account similar privileges. The default admin account is treated as the system account and it will not allow apps to be added or removed via the system account.

Ideally, when setting up your environment, you should be using a system account (part of admin group) to login to the server but setup SharePoint using a farm account (farm admin and run all the app pools)

Comment: I try this but not worked it..