# Error when creating SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have been following the following for configuring an app domain in our SharePoint 2013 environment. When I reach the step for New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy, I am getting the following error:

```
New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy : A
SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy with id
'4f0c42b1-5288-4057-8686-97464082df9b' already exists. Only one can exist per
farm.
At C:\Users\spfarm10\Desktop\Set_App_Domain.ps1:19 char:16
+ $proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy
```

What would be the best method for resolving this error?

[Setting up App Domain for On-Prem Deployment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/07/14/access-services-2013-setup-for-an-on-premises-installation.aspx)

[Error Occured in Deployment Step of App](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54617/error-occured-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 1):

After more digging and testing, this error originated from the SharePoint environment not having access to the internet to verify certificates. This causes us to try numerous time to configure different services, most of which resulted in errors, or the creation of multiple services and proxies.

The server was temporarily granted access to verify the certificates, and the excess service applications were removed. The I was able to create the App domain, which was the end goal.

This may or may not have been the best approach, but in this case, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have a subscription service and proxy, try to skip those two lines and continue with the app proxy and so on